# Centos/RHEL: Determine minimal set of packages to install given dependencies?

Tags: rhel, package-management, yum, rpm

Suppose I have a list of packages I want to install:

```
# yum install foo bar baz quux
```

but suppose that `baz` is a dependency of `foo`, and `quux` is a dependency of `baz`.

So, really, all I *actually* needed to run was:

```
# yum install foo bar
```

Is there a way, given a list of packages, to determine that minimal set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the lack of mutual dependencies, which is guaranteed, the following algorithm will yield the minimal set:

- for each package in the list, list all of its requirements (`rpm -qR foo`)
- for each package in the requirements, remove it from the list if it’s present

Listing `foo`’s requirements yields `baz` (presumably among others), and listing `baz`’s requirements yields `quux`, so both can be dropped. Note that you must list all requirements before removing anything, otherwise you risk keeping transitive requirements (`quux` in this case, if you remove `baz` as soon as `foo` is processed).

**However** your package list should reflect *your* dependencies, not the minimal set which results in your dependencies being installed. If you need `quux`, you should list it in your `yum install` command, otherwise if `baz` stops depending on it at some point, your installation will stop meeting your requirements.